# .NET 4.5 Semaphore WaitOne(0) doesn't block, but decrements semaphore count

Tags: c#, .net

Up to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189907%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of .NET 4.5 if I use WaitOne(Int32) method on some object of Semaphore class (or - generally - WaitHandle class) with 0 (zero) as its argument, it doesn't block and may be used for testing semaphore's current state:

"If millisecondsTimeout is zero, the method does not block. It tests the state of the wait handle and returns immediately."

To me it's highly confusing (or even misleading), because it doesn't block, but it decrements semaphore count by one. So if I use it like this:

```
If (!mySemaphore.WaitOne(0)) DoSomething();
```

then it may decrement my semaphore (if true), causing other threads to be unable to run. So we cannot use it like this for only testing semaphore's state. The correct use should be

```
If (!mySemaphore.WaitOne(0)) DoSomething();
Else mySemaphore.Release();
```

So it doesn't only test semaphore's state! Am I right?

Comment: Simply testing without decrementing does not make sense because the answer you get is immediately stale and useless, because some other thread can change that answer after it has been written for you to read, but before you have read it.

Comment: @CodeCaster Disregard, I'm just dumb.

Comment: OK, I could agree, but... Imagine reversed situation - when WaitOne(0) result is true - it doesn't change semaphore's state and the result is then useless, as meanwhile another thread could release the semaphore.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Correct, it does not only test the semaphore state, a better wording would be

> If millisecondsTimeout is zero, the method does not block. The method attempts to take a wait handle and returns immediately with the success or failure of that attempt.

Also your example is incorrect, correct way to use this would be

```
if (mySemaphore.WaitOne(0)) 
{
    try
    {
        DoSomething();
    }
    finally
    {
        //Only call release when WaitOne returns true, also put it in a finally 
        //block to make sure it always gets called.
        mySemaphore.Release();
    }
}
else
{
    //Do something else because the resource was not available.
}
```

You should only call `mySemaphore.Release()` when `mySemaphore.WaitOne` returns true, in your current example you are calling it only when it returns false.

Comment: You're right, it should DoSomething() when mySemaphore.WaitOne(0) returns true, I have just edited my post. +1 for the Try..finally part reminder